# How to fix url contains arabic characters

Tags: php

I want to get the url of each file in certain directory

i tried string concatenation (like: domain.folder1.folder2.file.mp3) but some folders and files is with arabic characters that make error when using the url.

example:

this is my code output:

String A :

https://linkimage2url.com/apps/quran full/محمد صديق المنشاوي/تسجيلات الإذاعة المصرية/009 - At-Taubah (The Repentance) سورة التوبة.mp3

this code is not working in some android devices

but the next code works with all devices

String B:

https://linkimage2url.com/apps/quran%20full/%D9%85%D8%AD%D9%85%D8%AF%20%D8%B5%D8%AF%D9%8A%D9%82%20%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%85%D9%86%D8%B4%D8%A7%D9%88%D9%8A/%D8%AA%D8%B3%D8%AC%D9%8A%D9%84%D8%A7%D8%AA%20%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A5%D8%B0%D8%A7%D8%B9%D8%A9%20%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%85%D8%B5%D8%B1%D9%8A%D8%A9/009%20-%20At-Taubah%20(The%20Repentance)%20%D8%B3%D9%88%D8%B1%D8%A9%20%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AA%D9%88%D8%A8%D8%A9.mp3

Note: i got String B from internet download manager that converts it automatically when i tried to use string A

my question is:

how to convert String A to String B by php

and is there better way to readdir and get the url of each file

My code is:

```
if(is_dir($parent)){
if($dh = opendir($parent)){
while(($file = readdir($dh)) != false){

if($file == "." or $file == ".."){
//...
} else { //create object with two fields

sort($file);
$fileName = pathinfo($file)['filename'];

if(is_dir($parent."/".$file)){
$data[] = array('name'=> $fileName, 'subname'=> basename($path), 'url'=> $path."/".$file, "directory"=> true);
} else {
$res = "https://linkimage2url.com".$path."/".$file;
$data[] = array('name'=> $fileName, 'subname'=> basename($path), 'url'=> $res , "directory"=> false);
}
```

Comment: have you tried Rawulrencode()?

Comment: yes but the output is different than Strig B and doesnt work

Comment: i get String B from internet download manager that converts it automatically when i tried to use string A

Comment: try htmlentities https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php

Comment: i tried urlencode , rawurlencode , htmlentities , htmlspecial char. not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this code worked for me

thanks every one

```
$res1 = "https://linkimage2url.com" .$path."/".$file;
$query = flash_encode ($res1);
$url = htmlentities($query);



 function flash_encode($string)
   {
      $string = rawurlencode($string);
      $string = str_replace("%2F", "/", $string);
      $string = str_replace("%3A", ":", $string);
      return $string;
   }
```

Comment: get a look to my answer, I think it works and more complete than this one :-)
in any case, I'm glad to help and  that you solved it

Comment: `<?php
  echo '<a href="' . rawurlencode("https://linkimage2url.com/apps/quran full/محمد صديق المنشاوي/تسجيلات الإذاعة المصرية/009 - At-Taubah (The Repentance) سورة التوبة.mp3") . '">' . htmlentities("https://linkimage2url.com/apps/quran full/محمد صديق المنشاوي/تسجيلات الإذاعة المصرية/009 - At-Taubah (The Repentance) سورة التوبة.mp3", ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8") . '</a>';
?>` may solve your question?

Answer (score 1):

Try this one, I've used once for a legacy project:

```
function encode_fullurl($url) {
$output = '';
$valid  = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789-_.~!*\'();:@&=+$,/?#[]%';
$length = strlen($url);
for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
    $character = $url[$i];
    $output   .= (strpos($valid, $character) === false ? rawurlencode($character) : $character); 
}
return $output;

}


$url ="https://linkimage2url.com/apps/quran full/محمد صديق المنشاوي/تسجيلات الإذاعة المصرية/009 - At-Taubah (The Repentance) سورة التوبة.mp3";
echo encode_fullurl($url);
```

output:

https://linkimage2url.com/apps/quran%20full/%D9%85%D8%AD%D9%85%D8%AF%20%D8%B5%D8%AF%D9%8A%D9%82%20%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%85%D9%86%D8%B4%D8%A7%D9%88%D9%8A/%D8%AA%D8%B3%D8%AC%D9%8A%D9%84%D8%A7%D8%AA%20%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A5%D8%B0%D8%A7%D8%B9%D8%A9%20%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%85%D8%B5%D8%B1%D9%8A%D8%A9/009%20-%20At-Taubah%20(The%20Repentance)%20%D8%B3%D9%88%D8%B1%D8%A9%20%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AA%D9%88%D8%A8%D8%A9.mp3

it is not very performing, but it should do what you need

Comment: sorry its not working .. the output is 

https://linkimage2url.com/apps/quran%20full/%D9%85%D8%AD%D9%85%D8%AF%20%D8%B5%D8%AF%D9%8A%D9%82%20%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%85%D9%86%D8%B4%D8%A7%D9%88%D9%8A/%D8%AA%D8%B3%D8%AC%D9%8A%D9%84%D8%A7%D8%AA%20%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A5%D8%B0%D8%A7%D8%B9%D8%A9%20%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%85%D8%B5%D8%B1%D9%8A%D8%A9/009%20-%20At-

that makes error http 500

Comment: Are you sure? I've tried with http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/ and it seems to works... (i've added the output url).
Link for testing: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/3da0b70eb26a42ac656a7c2ee5ec81ec09d6def6